# Why is column pushed right in alignat?

Tags: alignat

I thought that `alignat` inserted no extra spaces between columns. Then why in the following is the part `\left.(r \cos \theta + R) \sin \varphi,\right.` of the first row pushed toward the right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
F(\theta, \varphi)= & \left((r \cos \theta + R) \cos \varphi, \right. & \left.(r \cos \theta + R) \sin \varphi,\right.
\\
& & \left. r \sin \theta \cos (\varphi/2),\, r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\varphi/2)\,\right)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Seemingly misaligned 2nd component on right-hand side of 1st equation]

Comment: It's because the columns are alternatively flushed right, left, right and so on, hence the third column is flushed right. The "extra space" that appears here is only due to the second row, on which the content of the third column is larger.

Comment: Thatis because, as you used only  2 `&` instead of 3, the alignment point  of the second column is not specified, and by default, it is set at the end of the column, i.e. the latter is right-aligned.

Comment: @Bernard: Where do I put a 3rd `&` to avoid the misalignment?

Comment: I've updated my code – didn't notice you had `alignat{3}` for two columns! Also, I removed the pairs of `\left ... \right` which did nothing  to replace all of them by a single pair `\bigl( ... \bigr)` ((which can have  ampersands or line breaks in between).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a simple `split` environment with a single alignment point per line. I'd also get rid of the distracting `\left` and `\right` sizing directives (in particular, because they don't accomplish anything meaningful) and use `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
F(\theta, \varphi) &= \bigl[( r \cos\theta + R) \cos\varphi,\, (r \cos\theta + R) \sin\varphi, \\
&\qquad r \sin\theta \cos(\varphi/2),\, r \sin\theta \sin(\varphi/2) \bigr]
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps this way is the simplest and gives the most attractive result

Answer (score 4):

If you want, you can also use `witharrows`. Maybe the syntax may seem more natural (of course, the main usage of `witharrows` is to add arrows in such alignments).

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}    
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[format = rll]
F(\theta, \varphi)= & \bigl((r \cos \theta + R) \cos \varphi, &  (r \cos \theta + R) \sin \varphi,
\\
& &  r \sin \theta \cos (\varphi/2),\, r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\varphi/2)\,\bigr)
\end{DispWithArrows*}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code]

Comment: Oooh...that's a trick I never encountered before; useful!

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong tool: this wants `multline`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
F(\theta, \varphi)= \bigl((r \cos \theta + R) \cos \varphi, (r \cos \theta + R) \sin \varphi,
\\
r \sin \theta \cos (\varphi/2), r \sin \theta \sin (\varphi/2)\bigr)
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

No `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

Alternatively, `align`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
F(\theta, \varphi)= \bigl((r \cos \theta + R) \cos \varphi&, (r \cos \theta + R) \sin \varphi,
\\
&\quad r \sin \theta \cos (\varphi/2), r \sin \theta \sin (\varphi/2)\bigr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `multline` looks a bit stretched.  I'd be inclined to add `\qquad` at the two ends to narrow it.

Comment: Indeed, `multline` requires some fiddling to compress the dislay and, in particular, to align the 3rd entry in the list on the right-hand side of the equation with the 2nd one

Answer (score 3):

Use this (and remember that *n* alignment columns require 2 *n* – 1 `&`). Using  `\bigl(` and `bigr)`, which accept ampersands or line breaks in between, will save you  the plethora of `\left ... \right`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
F(\theta, \varphi)= & \bigl((r \cos \theta + R) \cos \varphi, & & (r \cos \theta + R) \sin \varphi,
\\
& & & r \sin \theta \cos (\varphi/2),\, r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\varphi/2)\,\bigr)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `alignat` adds no "padding", I'd add `\,` after `\varphi,`; the following parenthsis looks a bit too close,

Comment: `=&` is wrong; there's no need for multiple alignment points.

Comment: @egreg: I agree, but I supposed that in the real equations, there are other lines with an alignment on the  `=`  sign. Maybe this hypothesis was erroneous…